# What is the best way to validate if a value with decimals is in a defined range

Tags: java, decision-tree, design-decisions

I have a file with thresholds defined and these threshold are use to help to take decision.

The values looks like this:

```
"thresholds":[
    { "min": 0.0, "max": 0.25, "text": "VERY UNLIKELY" },
    { "min": 0.26, "max": 0.50, "text": "UNLIKELY" }
    { "min": 0.51, "max": 0.75, "text": "LIKELY" }
    { "min": 0.76, "max": 1.0, "text": "VERY LIKELY" }
]
```

The condition:

```
for (Threshold threshold : thresholds) {
    if ((threshold.getMin() <= predictionValue) &&
        (predictionValue <= threshold.getMax())) {
            return threshold.getText();
    }
}
```

If the value to check is something like 0.2500000001, it fall somewhere between 0.25 and 0.26. So I ask, what is the optimal way to determine if a value is in a certain range without having empty gap?

Should I add a parameter for precision and apply this precision on the min & max values? I don't want to have to configure the file with values like 0.259999999.

Comment: You could define the thing as a half-open interval where the upper limit value is not included. Example: min: 0 - max 0.26 <- and then just check if your value is >= min and < max

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Yes good idea!

Comment: If you want precision with decimals you can use BigDecimal class, make sure you use the BigDecimal(String val) constructor, because if you pass double/float directly it will still be imprecise:


https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 1):

You end up with this grey zone because you want to declare a boundary with 2 values. This does not work. I will give you an idea of how it works:

**What you should do:**

```
"thresholds":[
    { "max": 0.25, "text": "VERY UNLIKELY" },
    { "max": 0.50, "text": "UNLIKELY" }
    { "max": 0.75, "text": "LIKELY" }
    { "max": 1.0, "text": "VERY LIKELY" }
]
```

**And the condition:**

```
for (Threshold threshold : thresholds) {
    if (predictionValue < threshold.getMax()) {
            return threshold.getText();
    }
}
```

As you can see, one value suffices to define a boundary.

Comment: Yeah it's probably the best to handle this. Thanks